# PHP - Display mysql single record php via id from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

My HTML lists rows from my database table (venues), but now I want to view the records separately. The user should be able to click a row, and then be redirected to that single page and see details.

Here is the 1st page.

```
<?php

// Include the connection file.
include("func.inc.php");

//////Displaying Data/////////////


$venue_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['venue_id']);

$venue_id=$_GET['venue_id'];

$city=$_GET['city'];
$reason=$_GET['reason'];
$budget=$_GET['budget'];

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf(
   "SELECT city, reason, budget, venue_name, description, venue_id FROM venues WHERE city = '%s' AND reason = '%s' AND budget = '%s' ",
   mysql_real_escape_string($city),
   mysql_real_escape_string($reason),
   mysql_real_escape_string($budget)
);

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result == false) {
   die(mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query");
}

?>

<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>


<tr>
    <td> <a href="venue.php?venue_id=<?php echo $row['venue_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['venue_name']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['image']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } 

?>
```

Here is the 2nd page, the venue.php:

```
<?php

// Include the connection file.
include("func.inc.php");

$venue_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['venue_id']);
$venue_id = $_GET['venue_id'];

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM venues WHERE venue_id = "'.$venue_id.'" ',
mysql_real_escape_string($venue_id));


$result = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


if($result == false) {
   die(mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query");
}

?>
```

I'm close, but the $venue_id isn't carrying over to the next page and the single details aren't populating. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: In your first page, you're setting the URL as `venue.php?id=...`; so in the second page, the `$_GET` key will be `id` not `venue_id`

Comment: And as you're clearly just starting to learn; please consider using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables rather than the old MySQL extension which will officially be killed off before the end of this year.... it will help protect your database against possible SQL injection attacks without your needing to remember to escape everything

Comment: So now it sees the venue_id number, but I'm getting new errors.

Comment: Your `$venue_id` is injectible, escape it after setting it. What are errors?

Comment: @chris85 (Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /venue.php on line 25 -- Notice: No rows returned by: SELECT * FROM venues WHERE venue_id = "1" in /venue.php on line 26 -----Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in /venue.php on line 33

Comment: See the doc for that function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php. `This result comes from a call to mysql_query().` You change that into an array though `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`. Myabe make that `$result_array = ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is some issue in your code firstly.
Why do you do that :

```
$venue_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['venue_id']);
$venue_id=$_GET['venue_id'];
```

Really the thats not efficient. You can do for example :

```
$venue_id = (int) $_GET['venue_id'];
```

That way you cast the value as an integer (I think you value is an integer). And no need to make a mysql_real_escape_string (which is useful for text).

Secondly for you main issue, do you see in your first page, in the HTML that the venue_id is set in

```
<a href="venue.php?id=XXXX">
```

When you clic on it, does it is in the url of your landing page ?
like : [www.example.com/venue.php?id=XXXX](http://www.example.com/venue.php?id=XXXX)

Did you try to echo the `$_GET["venue_id"]` ?
The problem is that in your url you set `'id'` and in your landing page you search for `'venue_id'`

Put `<a href="venue.php?**venue_id**=XXXX">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the anchor to 'venue_id'. When I click on it, the url of the landing page is like: www.example.com/venue.php?venue_id=XXXX. However, now the errors read that no rows are being returned. @sym

Comment: Do you need help with that last problem ?

Comment: Ok enjoy and look at some coding best practices like this : https://www.corephp.com/blog/php-best-practices-that-you-must-follow/

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to working. After your recommendations, I had to delete a line:

```
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Thanks everyone!